# Spring Integration to poll folder and call REST with file contents

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

The use case is that I need to poll a folder on a remote server, and if a new file is copied to that folder, I need to call a REST get API with the file contents. The REST API will process the file contents using Spring batch.

I am trying to use Spring boot integration for that purpose but having issues finding my way. Is Spring Integration best suited for this purpose? If yes, can I have a simple example of just the Spring Integration picking up the file and calling the REST API?

Or can I simply use the Java Watcher service?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what is your remote folder, but you can't use Java `WatchService` for that purpose anyway. Typically the remote directory is on an (S)FTP. Spring Integration provides channel adapters to poll such a remote directory under the mentioned protocol.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound

You probably don't need to have a local copy of a remote service, then you can consider to use a streaming channel adapter instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-streaming

As far as a file content is emitted into a channel configured in that channel adapter, you can use an HTTP Outbound Channel Adapter to call some REST API: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/http.html#http-outbound

You can investigate samples project for some inspiration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples